# Is C++ the single language that have both pointers and references?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, pointers, reference

Amongst the programming languages I know and those I've been exposed to, C++ looks like the only one to have both pointers and references. Is it true?

Comment: its porbably worth remembering that just because a language has something it calls a reference or a pointer doesn't mean its 100% equivalent to c++ references or pointers e.g. c#

Comment: I am in fact wondering if any other language that has pointers, also have this ... kind of ... well ... dereferenced pointer that is creating sooOOO many difficulties to soooOOO (too) many programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algol 68 and Pascal certainly do. IIRC, Ada does too, though I don't remember all the details. PL/I did as well -- it may (easily) have been the first to include both.

Algol 68's references were really more like C++ pointers though. In C++, once you initialize a reference, it always refers to the same object. In Algol 68, you could "reseat" a reference, so it referred to a different object.

It's been a while since I used Pascal, but if memory serves its only use of references is for parameter passing (i.e. a `var` parameter passes by reference). I don't think you can create a reference other than as a parameter.

Ada allows you to mark parameters as `in`, `out`, or `inout`. If I recall correctly, some `inout` parameters are copied into the function, then copied back to the caller at the end, but others are pass by reference. As I said, I don't remember the details though.

Comment: It looks like Algol 68 only has `ref` (that are more like pointers), but not both.

Comment: I accept Pascal, that have pointers, and references even if limited to parameter passing. Don't know about Ada.

Comment: @dtrosset: you're right, my answer was poorly phrased -- I hadn't intended to say that Algol 68 had both as separate things, but that it has references that can do most pointer-like things, so it sort of has both as a single item.

Answer (score 3):

Google's [Go](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html) has both. Slices are references. I think it's not as general-purpose and clean-cut as in C++, where you can often pick  between a pointer and a reference yourself.

Comment: Right. But if I understand correctly, one can only take a slice of an array, not of any other type.

Answer (score 1):

C# has something similar, in that is has `unsafe` methods which can contain pointers.  Although pointers in C# are somewhat more limited.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is the only language that has what C++ calls pointers and references, yes. Just like Java is the only language that has Java classes, and Python is the only language that has Python functions.

Many languages have *something* called references, but they're rarely the exact same thing.

C# has something called references, which doesn't behave like C++ references, and if you use unsafe code, it has something called pointers too (which again aren't defined exactly like C++ pointers)

So really, it's a meaningless question. No other language has C++'s exact features, no. But many languages have *similar* features under the same names.

Comment: Think this might no longer be the case. D has pointers and references, and if I'm not mistaken they have semantics very close to, if not identical to C++'s